# Subsetting by summing number of values in clustered data in R

Tags: r, subset, multi-level

I am trying to solve a data formatting problem.
I have a data frame where the variables are leveled into schools and students. For example:

```
Schools  Students

SchoolA  Student1
SchoolA  Student2
SchoolA  Student3

SchoolB  Student4
SchoolB  Student5

SchoolC  Student6
```

I would like to create a subset of my dataset keeping only the schools that have more than X number of students (for example, at least 2).
Is there an easy way to do this in R? 
How could I create an extra variable (column) with the number of students per school so that I can subset based on that?
Thank you for your help in advance!

EDIT - - - - - -

Thank you very much for your responses. I have created an example for future reference.

```
 # creating a dataset
 Schools <- c('SchA','SchA','SchA','SchA','SchA',
   'SchB','SchB','SchB','SchB','SchB','SchB',
   'SchC','SchC')
 Students <- c('st1','st2','st3','st4','st5','st6',
          'st7','st8','st9', 'st10', 'st11', 'st12', 'st13')
 df <- data.frame(Schools, Students)

 install.packages('data.table')
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, if(.N > 4) .SD, Schools] # only schools A & B

 df[ with(df, as.numeric(ave(as.character(Students), Schools, FUN=length))) >2, ]
```

Is there a way to create an additional variable (School size) that would hold the number of students (unique to that particular school) per school?
If I could have a variable like this, I could subset based on that.

Comment: Is each row is unique student or sometimes you have several rows with the same student? If so, one way is (assuming `Students` is a factor) `df[with(df, ave(as.numeric(Students), Schools, FUN = function(x) length(x) > 1)), ]`. Which will return the subset without creating the extra column

Comment: Good question, there is one unique student per row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lapply()`

```
 student.count = 2 # depends on your choice 
 out = do.call(rbind, 
       lapply(split(df, f = df$Schools), 
       function(x){ 
       x$no.of.students = length(x$Students);
       x = subset(x, no.of.students > student.count)
       }))

#> out
#        Schools Students no.of.students
#SchA.1     SchA      st1              5
#SchA.2     SchA      st2              5
#SchA.3     SchA      st3              5
#SchA.4     SchA      st4              5
#SchA.5     SchA      st5              5
#SchB.6     SchB      st6              6 
#SchB.7     SchB      st7              6
#SchB.8     SchB      st8              6
#SchB.9     SchB      st9              6
#SchB.10    SchB     st10              6
#SchB.11    SchB     st11              6
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunatelly, it does not subset

Comment: I did not check the edit in your question, I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df)[, if(.N > 1) .SD, Schools]
```

Also using @flodel's answer in the duplicated question as an inspiration:

```
dat[table(Students)[Students] >2]
```

If the condition is based on the length of `unique` number of 'Students' per 'Schools'

```
setDT(df)[, if(uniqueN(Students) > 1) .SD, Schools]
```

A similar approach using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Schools) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(Students) > 1)
   #or depending on the condition
   #filter(n() > 1)
```

#### Update

If you need to create a column before subsetting (using the new dataset)

```
setDT(df)[, no.of.students := .N, Schools][, if(.N  > 4) .SD, Schools]
#     Schools Students no.of.students
# 1:    SchA      st1              5
# 2:    SchA      st2              5
# 3:    SchA      st3              5
# 4:    SchA      st4              5
# 5:    SchA      st5              5
# 6:    SchB      st6              6
# 7:    SchB      st7              6
# 8:    SchB      st8              6
# 9:    SchB      st9              6
#10:    SchB     st10              6
#11:    SchB     st11              6

df %>% 
   group_by(Schools) %>% 
   mutate(no.of.students=n()) %>%
   filter(n()>4)
```

Comment: thank you that works, including the use of dplyr that I didn't add in my edit

Answer (score 2):

This succeeds:

```
 dat[ with(dat, as.numeric(ave(as.character(Students), Schools, FUN=length))) >2, ]
```

First test case had only your example, but I noticed that without the as.numeric around the `ave` function, that I was getting a character result and worrie that it might failed  a test with "120" > "20" which will retrun FALSE. Adding the as.numeric fixed the problem. To Arenbergs concern about possible repetition of student names one could certain wrap `unique()` around the length argument inside the ave-FUN.

This would create the classification variable:

```
dat$snum <-with(dat, as.numeric( ave( as.character(Students), Schools, FUN=length)))
```

Comment: thank you, that works perfectly, I was wondering whether there is a way to create a variable 'School size' which I could use for subsetting

Comment: Using `ave` would have working for that (if you had asked that question.) As it was not asked, creating a new variable would have altered the data in a manner that wasn't requested.